# sortn starting at row x

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the `sortn` formula (see below), which works like a charm. However, I want the thirty results showing to start on a predefined row (it is predefined to start on row 1). Is this possible? Basically `[n]` starting on **row x**.

```
=SORTN(A1:AB9691, 30 , 5, true)
```

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) to return 30 values skipping the `n` first rows. If my comprehension is correct, then you can use [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) to reach your goal. Using the [`OFFSET`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#offset) clause you can skip the firsts `n` rows, you only have to increase your `SORTN` results by `n`.

```
=QUERY({YOUR SORTN HERE},"SELECT * OFFSET n")
```

Don't hesitate to ask me further questions if you have doubts.